# django Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm learning this tutorial about django todoapp. I want to display all user's **content** (their todolists) and well im getting that error see the title I'm using google's login auth

here's my views.py

```
def todoView(request,):
  all_todo_items = Todoitem.objects.filter(userid=id).values_list('id', flat=True)
  return render(request, 'todoapp.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})
```

here's my models.py

```
class Todoitem(models.Model):
content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
userid = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='userid', blank=True, 
null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'todoitem'

def __str__(self):
    return self.content

class AuthUser(models.Model):
password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
email = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'auth_user'
```

here's my todoapp.html

```
{% load socialaccount %}
<body>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Welcome, {{ user.username }} !</p>

{% else %}
<h1>My Google Login Project</h1>
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Login with Google</a>
{% endif %}
<h2>My Personal TodoApp Project</h2>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">List of Todos</th>
</tr>
{% for todo_items in all_items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{todo_items.content}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect *id* comes from the path. So, add id parameter in your function:

```
def todoView(request, id=None):
  all_todo_items = Todoitem.objects.filter(userid=id).values_list('id', flat=True)
  return render(request, 'todoapp.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})
```

Comment: ok error gone now but its not showing the contents

Comment: i think its not showing the content because i use todo_items.content instead of todo_items.user.content

Answer (score 1):

You pass the `Todoitem`s of the logged in user with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def todoView(request):
    all_todo_items = Todoitem.objects.filter(userid=request.user)
    return render(request, 'todoapp.html', {'all_items': all_todo_items})
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).